Regex to verify properly formatted person's name ending with Sr or Jr
I am trying to create a Perl regular expression that will match a person's name. When the name ends with Sr or Jr it is formatted properly with a leading comma and space, and ending with a period.
For example:
Should match:
John Smith
John Smith, Sr.
John Smith, Jr.

Should not match:
John Smith Sr
John Smith, Sr
John Smith, SR.
John Smith Sr.
John Smith, John Smith Sr.
John Smith-

Must also be properly capitalized, i.e. Sr or Jr not sr, SR, sR, jr, JR, or jR.
Name should not end with any punctuation, except for a period when Sr or Jr is used.
I tried
^(?!.(Jr|Sr)(?<!,\sJr.)(?<!,\sSr.)$).$

But the above Regex allows for several names that are not acceptable, i.e.
John Smith,
John Smith Sr.
I then found:
^([A-Za-z]+['-]?[A-Za-z]\s)([A-Za-z]+['-]?[A-Za-z]*)(,\s(Jr|Sr).)?$ 

but it allowed name to end in a hyphen, John Smith-, which should not be acceptable.

so Sr is not going to be allowed as a last name?

Please read Falsehoods Programmers Believe About Names.

Match everything up to the last word char that isn't "Sr" or "Jr", then optionally allow ", Sr." or ", Jr." before end:
.*\w(?<![SJ]r)(, [SJ]r\.)?$

See live demo.
Although not "bulletproof", it works for all your test cases and should be good enough judging by your examples.

Note that you don't need a .* at the beginning of a match, especially with an anchor at the end.

The trick in these sorts of problem is to use more than one pattern. At some point you'll want to change the big, complicated, single pattern and you'll break something.
First, match all the ones that are easy. Forget about matching everything that comes before the part you care about because there are infinite ways that names will vary:
/, [SJ]r\.$/

Now that you've matched all of those, the next pattern doesn't have to worry about those cases. Then filter out all of the ones that end in the wrong thing, so those are removed:
! /(?: [SJ]r\.?|-)$/

You might combine these like this:
use v5.10;

while (<DATA>) {
    chomp;
    print +( /, [SJ]r\.$/ or ! /(?: [SJ]r\.?|-)$/i ) ? '+' : '-';
    say "  $_";
    }


__END__
John Smith
John Smith, Sr.
John Smith, Jr.
John Smith Sr
John Smith, Sr
John Smith, SR.
John Smith Sr.
John Smith, John Smith Sr.
John Smith-

And, you get this output, which matches the limited cases you've presented here:
+   John Smith
+   John Smith, Sr.
+   John Smith, Jr.
-   John Smith Sr
-   John Smith, Sr
-   John Smith, SR.
-   John Smith Sr.
-   John Smith, John Smith Sr.
-   John Smith-

But, you'll probably find that as you run into additional cases, you'll discover more and more weird cases and you'll want additional filters. Dealing with people's names is one of the toughest things out there.

Falsehoods Programmers Believe About Names
Personal names around the world

Now the problem is that you shouldn't mess with names if you don't have to. If you think everything ending in some variation of [SJ]r\.? should be ,  [SJ]r\., just change one to the other, maybe with something like this:
my $changed = s/,? ([SJ])r\.?$/, \u${1}r./ir;

Then, ignore everything else instead of trying to match it.
However, when you do this, you are going to annoy some of the people who like to write their names in certain ways, even if you don't like it or agree with it. And, you are going to annoy some people who used that suffix for a completely different reason that you didn't even know about.

I think the following expression should meet your requirements:
^[A-Za-z -]+(, (Jr|Sr)\.)?(?<! Sr| Jr |-)$

It works like this:
^[A-Za-z -]+ = at the beginning of the line there are one or more letters, spaces or hyphens
(, (Jr|Sr).)? = optionally followed by ", Sr." or ", Jr."
(?<! Sr| Jr |-)$ = string does NOT end with Jr., Sr. or hyphen.
You can see the regex working in action at https://regex101.com/r/q1CVCT/1

Don't try to match what comes before. That is the path of madness.
